# Transformations between coordinate systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

I have three three-dimensional orthogonal coordinate systems, O, A and B. A and B are the result of two different transformations from O. I now want to calculate the transformation matrix R, which takes you from A to B. R should be the rotation and translation with respect to coordinate system A, not the original coordinate system O.

Which of the following is correct?

(1) B = A * R
or
(2) B = R * A

By doing some simple worked examples, it seems that (1) is correct. However, my intuition says that (2) is correct, because the transformation to A should be applied before the transformation to B, via R. Which is it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) is correct.

It is good to have a deeper understanding of the objects involved here. Let’s say we are talking about a three-dimensional vector space $V$. Then a coordinate system consists of three linearly independent vectors, e.g. $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3), a_i ∈ V$. It gives a natural isomorphism $$ℝ^3 ∋ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} ↦ xa_1+ya_2+za_2 ∈ V,$$ which I will denote by $\tilde{A}$.

In the case where $V = ℝ^3$, the coordinate system $A$ can be thought of as a matrix, where the basis vectors $a_i$ are the column vectors. Then the isomorphism $\tilde{A}: ℝ^3 → V = ℝ^3$ is given by left-multiplication with that matrix.

Notice however that the operation “write a vector in coordinates with respect to coordinate system A” is given by the inverse $\tilde{A}^{-1}$ of the isomorphism $\tilde{A}$. So for $V = ℝ^3$ this is left-multiplication by $A^{-1}$, the inverse matrix of $A$.

Now your question becomes: which matrix $R$, acting on the coordinate representation under $A$ gives the coordinate representation of $B$? According to the above note that means $$R ∘ \tilde{A}^{-1} = \tilde{B}^{-1}$$ and in the case $V = ℝ^3$ this is equivalent to $$R⋅A^{-1} = B^{-1} ⇔ A = B ⋅ R.$$

---

*Advanced Note*: When thinking about a manifold $M$, the same reasoning leads to the right action of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ on the frame bundle $\mathrm{GL}(M)$.